# Receive payments to a non-primary email address while doing reference transactions

Tags: paypal

I'm currently using Paypal's reference transactions using billing agreements to receive payments from customers. The merchant account I'm using has multiple email addresses and we would like to receive payments to a specific email address. Does anyone have any idea on how this can be achieved ? I'm not sure if I can specify the email address to receive payments on, while doing reference transactions or SetExpressCheckout or creating a billing agreement or all of those.

Answer (score 0):

The e-mail notifications for API call transactions will always be sent to the primary e-mail address on the account - sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response Patrick. But I'm not asking for the email notifications but the email address to which the funds will be credited as. Say, I have a@example.com (as primary), b@example.com email addresses added to our company PayPal account, and we use reference transactions. We want to receive the funds to b@example.com. But, since a@example.com is the primary email, all the funds are credited to it, meaning all the payment history shows a@example.com as the receiver. We need to receive the funds on the other email for accounting purposes.